# laravel controller passing id from selected item but no data is being passed to the edit method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I get an eloquent collection to my index page and when i click on my edit button the url changes accordingly to the id that i need to delete or edit the data but however i dont get any data send in my edit page.

index page

```
<form action="/admin/taken/{{ $taak->ID }}" method="post" class="deleteForm">
@method('delete')
@csrf
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"
              data-toggle="tooltip"
              title="{{ $taak->werknaam }} verwijderen">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
              </button>
</form>
```

index function()

```
$taken = Userwork::join('works','work_id','=','works.id')
            ->join('places','place_id','=','places.id')
            ->join('time_slots','works.id','=','time_slots.work_id')
            ->with('user')
            ->select('*','user_works.id as ID','works.name as werknaam','places.*','time_slots.start_hour')
            ->where('time_slots.date',$datum)
            ->where('places.name',$loc)
            ->get();
        $result = compact('taken','locaties','datums','loc');
        Json::dump($result);

        return view('admin.taken.index', $result);
```

[image]

edit function

```
public function edit(UserWork $taak)
    {
        dd($taak);
    }
```

outcome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that route is correctly defined? Post your route here if you can.

Your edit route shoud be like so:

```
Route::get('/admin/taken/{taak}/edit', 'YourController@edit');
```

Comment: Route::resource('taken','admin\TakenController');

Comment: could you try changing it to `Route::resource('admin/taken','TakenController');` and run `php artisan route:clear`